# Align a set of inline-blocks by a middle element

Tags: html, css

Consider we have a bunch of inline-blocks in a row:

```
<div class="elements-row">
  <div class="element">January</div>
  <div class="element">February</div>
  <div class="element">March</div>
  <div class="element featured">April</div>
  <div class="element">May</div>
  <div class="element">June</div>
  <div class="element">July</div>
<div>
```

---

```
.elements-row {
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.elements-row .element {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #abb8c2;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.elements-row .element.featured {
    margin: 0 40px;
    color: #4a667f;
}
```

Is there a way to **horizontally** align the row the way that `.featured` block always remains in the middle of the `.elements-row` block no matter what other elements width is (its' content is dynamic). Elements are allowed to go out of row's boundaries, but a space between all elements except of `.featured` should be constant.

[A demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/dukeimg/pen/GEYxVW)

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align:middle` on all of them?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I meant `align` as `text-align` (meaning horizontally). I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```css
.elements-row {
    height: 140px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.elements-row .element {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #abb8c2;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.elements-row .element.featured {
    margin: 0 40px;
    color: #4a667f;
}

.elements-center {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.elements-left {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.elements-right {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-row">
    <div class="elements-center">
        <div class="elements-left">
            <div class="element">January</div>
            <div class="element">February</div>
            <div class="element">March</div>
        </div>
        <div class="element featured">April</div>
        <div class="elements-right">
            <div class="element">May</div>
            <div class="element">June</div>
            <div class="element">July</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnxcg6xg/)... at least something to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Using flex this would also be possible.

You can check what I mean by stretching the window.
Instead of using `justify-content: space-around` you might want to use `justify-content: space-between`.

More information about flex can be found at [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

---

**Update:**

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv78dhvk/2/) with the new code, it  probably works better if you want to try and resize the window.

```css
.elements-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.element {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #abb8c2;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.featured {
  color: #AAA;
}

.elements-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}

.elements-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-row">
  <div class="elements-left">
    <div class="element">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="element">February</div>
    <div class="element">March</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element featured">April</div>
  <div class="elements-right">
    <div class="element">May</div>
    <div class="element">June</div>
    <div class="element">July</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Old code, might be useful for somebody else:**

Also a link to [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv78dhvk/)

```css
.elements-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.element {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #abb8c2;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.featured {
  color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-row">
      <div class="element">January</div>
      <div class="element">February</div>
      <div class="element">March</div>
      <div class="element featured">April</div>
      <div class="element">May</div>
      <div class="element">June</div>
      <div class="element">July</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried to use flexboxes. As you can see, `.featured` block it going a little bit to the right. Imagine if one of left elements is twice longer than now, `.featured` is gonna shift a lot then.